# No Data Sources show in Google Fit

Tags: wear-os, android-sensors, google-fit

I am trying to record location and speed from the Sensors API in Google Fit in my Watch Face Service (Android Wear). Here's the code I use:

```
private void connectFitnessDataListeners() {
    Fitness.SensorsApi.findDataSources(mGoogleApiClient,
        new DataSourcesRequest.Builder()
            .setDataTypes(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SAMPLE)
            .setDataTypes(DataType.TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE)
            .setDataTypes(DataType.TYPE_SPEED)
            // Can specify whether data type is raw or derived.
            .setDataSourceTypes(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
            .build())
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataSourcesResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DataSourcesResult dataSourcesResult) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Find Data Sources: " + dataSourcesResult.getStatus().toString());
                    for (DataSource dataSource : dataSourcesResult.getDataSources()) {
                        //only include dataSources from the watch
                        Log.i(TAG, "Data source found: " + dataSource.toString());
                        Log.i(TAG, String.format("Data Source device %s and type: %s", dataSource.getDevice().toString(),dataSource.getDataType().getName()));
                        if (dataSource.getDevice() != Device.getLocalDevice(getBaseContext())) continue;

                        //FIXME: Turn this into a loop over an array
                        if (dataSource.getDataType().equals(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SAMPLE) && (mActivitySampleListener == null)) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Data source for ACTIVITY_SAMPLE found!  Registering.");
                            mActivitySampleListener = registerFitnessDataListener(dataSource, DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SAMPLE);
                        } else if (dataSource.getDataType().equals(DataType.TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE) && (mLocationSampleListener == null)) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Data source for LOCATION_SAMPLE found!  Registering.");
                            mLocationSampleListener = registerFitnessDataListener(dataSource, DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SAMPLE);
                        } else if (dataSource.getDataType().equals(DataType.TYPE_SPEED) && (mSpeedListener == null)) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Data source for SPEED found!  Registering.");
                            mSpeedListener = registerFitnessDataListener(dataSource, DataType.TYPE_SPEED);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    );
}
```

However, when I run this in an otherwise working onConnected call, I get no DataSources in the for loop (the `Find Data Sources` log call shows success).

Any thoughts as to what I should pursue?

**UPDATE**: 
If I remove the `setDataSourceTypes` restriction, I get only this:

```
Data source found: DataSource{derived:Application{com.google.android.gms::null}:Device{Sony:SmartWatch 3:15e991d4::3:2}::DataType{com.google.speed[speed(f)]}}
Data Source device Device{Sony:SmartWatch 3:15e991d4::3:2} and type: com.google.speed
```

So why don't I see location information from the GPS?

Answer (score 0):

This was my developer error: setDataTypes takes a vararg set of DataTypes; in my example I was only setting DataType for TYPE_SPEED